# Need to add a sub folder in Nginx location redirect with regex

Tags: nginx, redirect, nginx-location

I am using Nginx location redirect in my application below is my code

```
location /engineering/relational-database-management-100/ {
   return 301 /engineering/blog/relational-database-management-100/;
}
```

I have around many blogs and need to redirect them all. if I want to do the same with regex how can I do it? Just wanted to add blog before the slug

```
location /engineering/xxxxxxxxxxxx/ {
   return 301 /engineering/blog/xxxxxxxxxxxx/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex match location:

```
location ~ ^/engineering(/.*) {
    return 301 /engineering/blog$1;
}
```

If you want to preserve query arguments, use

```
   return 301 /engineering/blog$1$is_args$args;
```